# Accidentally restricted TexShop from a folder

Tags: filesystem-access

I made an extremely stupid error.  I installed TexShop on a new computer and the first time I went to compile a document, it asked me if it was ok for TexShop to access the Documents folder.  I, completely accidentally, clicked No instead of allow.  I can't seem to figure out how to undo whatever I have done or have it ask me again.  If I move my .tex files to another location, then it works fine, so somehow I have accidentally restricted the Documents folder.  Without changing the entire file structure of my computer, and just never making a TeX document in my Documents folder again, does anyone know what setting I need to change to fix this.  I have been googling for hours and have found nothing.

Comment: Since this is more of an Mac OS issue rather than a TeX issue you may have better luck asking at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: See for example https://nektony.com/duplicate-finder-free/folders-permission for instructions (although for a different program, but it may apply here as well).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently, not with TexShop, but Techmaker. But the symptoms were the same. I got the question if I want to give access to the Documents folder to texmaker when trying to compiled a file, and I replied "No" because I have not got this question before and was a little suspicious. Afterwords everything went as for you.

My solution was simply that instead of clicking on the TeX file to open it, I right-clicked and then chose Open -> texmaker.app (default). After that I could compile the file as before.

I do not know if your problem has already been solved, and if not, whether the above would help you, but I thought to share this. I am using Ventura 13.2.1 and texmaker 5.0.3.